# I cant load negative numbers in arm cortex-m0 assembly

Tags: assembly, stm32

I am using a nucleo board STM32L053R8, with cortex-m0 cpu. I use assembly language to create a simple exercise, which takes an array and calculates the sum of the elements. The array has positive and negative numbers. In my program, I use this directives:

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb
.section .text
.globl main
```

I have created an "array" of byte size numbers like below:

```
my_data: .word  +13,-10,+9,+14,-18,-9,+12,-19,+16
```

First and foremost, I wanted to test that the register r3, which is responsible for taking the items each time the loop occurs, that will be able to see the exact number of the array. Just because I have both negative and positive values, I used the ldrsb in order to load the values into the register like below:

```
main:
            movs    r0,#0   //Count the numbers in the array
            movs    r1,#9   //Define the total length of the array
            ldr     r2,=my_data //Load the address of my_data to r0 register
loop:
            ldrsb   r3,[r2]  //Take the value from the "array"
            cmp     r0,r1    //Compare the registers
            beq     exit     //If they are equal, exit
            adds    r0,r0,#1 //Otherwise, move forward 
            adds    r2,r2,#4 //Continue to the next element of the array.
            b       loop
exit:
            b exit
            .align
            .end
```

By doing that, I have an error from the compiler which says that:

```
Error: cannot honor width suffix -- `ldrsb r3,[r2]'
```

If I don't use the ldrsb and try with ldrb, then it compiles correctly, without any error, it searching the elements of the array properly, and it is able to exit when the counter(r0) reaches the 9 as the total length of the array. However, the negative numbers from the array cannot be loaded correctly. For instance, instead of loading the value -10, it is loading lets say a random positive value? like 250.

Is that any other directive that I am missing? How to load all the signed numbers correctly? Could be a bug of the compiler or something else in cortex-m0, when we are using the ldrsb?

Comment: Your data are words, why do you load bytes. Just use `ldr` and it should work. If you insist, use `ldrb r3, [r2]; sxtb r3, r3`

Comment: The problem you observe is that `ldrsb` is only available as `ldrsb Rt, [Rn, Rm]` not as `ldrsb Rt, [Rn, #imm]`.  This is a limitation of the ARMv6-M architecture.  However, in the big picture, Jester's advice is what you need to make your program work.